# jquery ui dialog modal only opens once using class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
        $(".groomed").click(function() {
            var modal = $(".dash-modal", this).dialog({
                    height:400,
                    width:800,
                    modal:true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    Cancel: function() {
                            $(".dash-modal", this).dialog("destroy");
                    }
            });
            console.log(modal);
            modal.dialog('open');
    });
```

I have gone threw all of the stack overflows and they all deal with a id selector and I need this to work with a class selector. Code is included above.

The console logs the following for the first click:

[div#ui-id-2.dash-modal info ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content, prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1], context: tr.groomed, selector: ".dash-modal", constructor: function, init: function…]

And this for the second:
[prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1], context: tr.groomed, selector: ".dash-modal", constructor: function, init: function…]

So it looks like the entire functionality is being removed after the modal is closed, the api says to use destroy, I've tried that with both close: and cancel:

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  Cancel: function() {
                            $(".dash-modal", this).dialog("destroy");
                    }
```

by this you destroy the dialog box

close dialog box to use according to your requirement

```
 Cancel: function() {
                            $(".dash-modal", this).dialog("close");
                    }
```

reference **[dialog close](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close)** and **[dialog destroy](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy)**

Comment: Using close has the same effect as destroy and the dialog only opens once, thanks though.

Comment: $(".dash-modal", this) change in  $(".dash-modal").

Comment: This has no change in the expected result.

Comment: close is used at the place of cancel because cancel is not an any parameter in dialog box and if you want to use cancel then make a button with cancel text then use it

Comment: close: function() {
                                $(".dash-modal").dialog("close");
                        }   This does not work either. :(

Comment: Perhaps it is best to note when closing the dialog it appears the div holding the content is removed from the DOM, how do I prevent this?

Comment: close: function() {
                                $(".dash-modal").dialog("destroy");
                        }

Comment: you find your answer :) @morissette